# Как увеличить скорость перемещения div

Tags: reactjs

Как увеличить скорость перемещения div или сделать так что когда удерживаешь его левой кнопкой мыши он не уходил за курсор и не переставал двигаться. Надеюсь понятно объяснил ну я думаю как вы посмотрите поймете о чем я. Вот код [КОД](https://codesandbox.io/s/prjf2t)

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой сайт, [https://yolo-mark-pwa.github.io/](https://yolo-mark-pwa.github.io). Что он делает вам не принципиально, важно, что там поверх картинок можно квадраты размещать и двигать

> Если вы начинающий разработчик, перед тем как ставить из npm готовое решение, попробуйте один раз написать самостоятельно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код сайта [размещен тут](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/tree/master/packages/yolo-mark-pwa). Вас интересует функция `dragHandler` из файла [area-selector.ts](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/blob/master/packages/yolo-mark-pwa/src/webcomponents/area-selector.ts#L252) на 252 строке. Думаю, можно чуть упростить

```js
let [x1, y1] = [0, 0]; // позиция мыши относительно родительского блока
let [TOP, LEFT] = [0, 0]; // отступ сверху и слева для перемещаемого прямоугольника

let [HEIGHT, WIDTH] = [0, 0]; // ширина и высота перемещаемого прямоугольника

const dragHandler = ({ pageX, pageY }) => {

  // Смещение позиции относительно прокрутки страницы
  const {scrollX, scrollY} = window;
  pageX -= scrollX;
  pageY -= scrollY;

  {
    // Смещение позиции относительно родительского элемента
    const { top, left } = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    [x1, y1] = [Math.max(pageX - left, 0), Math.max(pageY - top, 0)];
  }

  // делаем перетягивание прямоугольника по геометрическому центру
  const [top, left] = [Math.max(y1 - (HEIGHT / 2), 0), Math.max(x1 - (WIDTH / 2), 0)];
  const { height, width } = parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();

  // не даем прямоугольнику уехать за границы
  TOP = top + HEIGHT > height ? TOP : top;
  LEFT = left + WIDTH > width ? LEFT : left;

}
```